# JMeter testing authentication with WebSocket connection

Tags: json, jmeter, automated-tests

I have testing my application (this only back end) in Jmeter. I doing functional test in JMeter.
Now I want to testing authorization.
My authorization is following: open WebSocket connection and then send JSON.stringify as KeyService.

What I can testing in JMeter this?
I think first added to ThreadGroup in Test Plan - WebSocket Open Connection and set Server name and port,. next WebSocket P{ing/Pong, next WebSocket Single Write Sample - and this in Request data I think written as sstring format Key so for example "1234566788" which is in json format.
and next added WebSocket Single Read Sampler?

Is it correctly doing test? what else add?
maybe I should add Json Extractor (or something other?) and in this written content json.stringify file ?
how is it the best way to tested this in JMeter?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to test something with JMeter in particular or load test anything in general is to put it under anticipated load and **make sure that each JMeter thread (virtual user) performs exactly the same actions as real user (or application) would do**.

In other words, well-behaved load test must represent [system under test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_under_test) real-life usage as close as possible, better with 100% accuracy, otherwise such test will not make a lot of sense.

The general recommendation is recording the traffic between system under test and "consumer" - browser, application, other server using a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and then re-create the same traffic using JMeter so requests would be **exactly the same** (apart from dynamic parameters which need to be [correlated](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter))

In your case if the test scenario is about logging in you might want to verify whether you're really got logged in after sending a corresponding request(s), you can use [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) in order to check response code, message and/or body and conditionally fail the sampler if response contains the data it shouldn't (or does not contain the data it should)

Comment: ok, thank you very much !  but in this specyfic case, how I exactly (step by step) can testing, if authorisation is correctly.this working by send example socket JSON stringIfy ServiceKey:"key"

Comment: What Dmitri means is this: (1) start WireShark and set a capture filter with the name/port of your server. (2) start your client and let it perform the authentication step. (3) stop WireShark. (4) inspect the WebSocket frames in the WireShark trace and copy the messages your client has sent to your JMeter test script. (5) start another WireShark capture, start your JMeter test and let WireShark capture its behaviour. (6) compare result from JMeter test capture with client capture, adapt JMeter test script accordingly. (7) goto 5.